# How to get the glob list editor in vscode extension settings

Tags: vscode-extensions

The settings editor can do this

[image: glob list edit]

which produces similar to this in the settings file

```json
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true,
    "**/.zorg": true
  },
```

In `package.json` this contribution

```json
          "print.folder.exclude": {
            "default": [],
            "type": "array",
            "description": "%print.folder.exclude%"
          },
```

just gets a link to edit the file as json.

Declaring it as an object doesn't help. How do I get the glob list editor?

Comment: When looking into VS Code source code you can see that some settings properties are handled special. The code making use of [this method](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/284ed44c1e12d219d5916e5ab11534ba7e0f0787/src/vs/workbench/contrib/preferences/browser/settingsTreeModels.ts#L570) will provide the "Add Pattern"-styled config template. We "ordinary" extension authors don't have access to that kind of list editor, but only what is documented [in the official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#Configuration-schema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised this as an issue on the vscode GitHub repository.

The maintainers told me how to do it. They updated the documentation which should appear in the next release.

```json
          "print.folder.exclude": {
            "default": [
              "bin",
              "obj",
              "**/*.bin",
              "**/*.exe",
              "**/*.dll",
              "**/*.hex",
              "**/*.pdb",
              "**/*.pdf"
            ],
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "description": "%print.folder.exclude%"
          },
```

This produces an array of strings rather than an object, but you get the same editor.